# How to handle Firebase auth in single page app

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-security

I am using firebase simple login auth with angularjs and I want to create a single page app.
Before this, I have tried using `service`, `main controller` to handle it but I don't think it is good enough because I have to call FirebaseAuthClient() every time there is a route.
I also try to put FirebaseAuthClient() in angularjs .run() which initialize when app is start.
But it won't work when there is a route, I think it is because not a full page load.

Ok,
And here is what I want,

- except login page, every route (pages) are required login.
- A global FirebaseAuthClient() checking on every route so I don't need to call it again.
- A global `user` which return from FirebaseAuthClient()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand. You only need to initialize FirebaseAuthClient and all login() once in your entire app. It's a singleton, and your auth credentials apply to any Firebase operations you perform.

What makes you think that this is not the case? What sorts of errors are you seeing?

Comment: Hi, I finally figured out whats my problem. Here, I make it simple. Since single page app is not a full page load. How can I handle "is user logged in" in every route?  
Calling FirebaseAuthClient() every time a route changes?
I'm not sure is this related to angularjs or firebase.

Comment: You should probably just remember the last result returned to you by FirebaseAuthClient. You don't need to call it again.

Comment: Where should I store the auth info for later use?
Cookie or $rootScope in angularjs?

Is there anyway I can call directly auth.id (user id) after user authenticated?

Comment: I don't know enough about Angular to give a good answer here. Definitely not a cookie (those are only for storing data across page load, which we do already for you). Perhaps somehow more familiar with Angular can help you here. A global variable would work fine, though might not be a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was using before moving auth over to Singly. Maybe it helps?

```
p4pApp.factory('firebaseAuth', function($rootScope) {
var auth = {},
FBref = new Firebase(p4pApp.FIREBASEPATH);

auth.broadcastAuthEvent = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('authEvent');
};

auth.client = new FirebaseAuthClient(FBref, function(error, user) {
    if (error) {
    } else if (user) {
        auth.user = user;
        auth.broadcastAuthEvent();
    } else {
        auth.user = null;
        auth.broadcastAuthEvent();
    }
});

auth.login = function() {
    this.client.login('facebook');
};

auth.logout = function() {
    this.client.logout();
};

return auth;
});
```

The AuthCtrl is common to all/most of my pages.

```
var AuthCtrl = function($scope, firebaseAuth) {
$scope.login = function() {
    firebaseAuth.login();
};

$scope.logout = function() {
    firebaseAuth.logout();
};

$scope.isLoggedIn = function() {
    return !!$scope.user;   
};

// src: Alex Vanston (https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma)
$scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
    var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
    if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
        if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
            fn();
        }
    } else {
        this.$apply(fn);
    }
};

$scope.$on('authEvent', function() {
    $scope.safeApply(function() {
        $scope.user = firebaseAuth.user;
    });
});
};
```

From within the AuthCtrl you can just call isLoggedIn() to see if the user is logged in or not.